# SharePoint default Column values are added to all documents of a library even if the specific contenttype does not includes the column

Tags: column, default

in our document libraries documents are assigned to different contenttypes. These contenttypes share some columns but not all. If we now define default values for a managed metadata column, all documents will get the default value, even those documents that do not have this column. Because of this, when filtering with the column, you also get documents that do not fit at all.

Is this a default behaiviour or do we have a bug in our sharepoint system (SharePoint 2016 on prem)